# Center SVG viewbox X and Y based on content

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Let's say I have the following SVG:

```html
 <svg width="640" height="480" viewbox="0 0 640 480" style="border: 1px dotted black;">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" stroke="black"></line> 
  <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100" stroke="black"></line> 
  <line x1="100" y1="100" x2="0" y2="100" stroke="black"></line> 
  <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="0" y2="0" stroke="black"></line> 
 </svg>
```

This draws a square in the top left corner of the SVG.

If I want to move the viewbox so the square is centerd, I can change the viewbox X and Y like this:

```html
<svg width="640" height="480" viewbox="-270 -190 640 480" style="border: 1px dotted black;">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" stroke="black"></line> 
  <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100" stroke="black"></line> 
  <line x1="100" y1="100" x2="0" y2="100" stroke="black"></line> 
  <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="0" y2="0" stroke="black"></line> 
 </svg>
```

My question is, can the same result be achieved without changing the viewbox X and Y nor the lines Xs and Ys?

Comment: You could wrap all of the lines in a `<g>` element and then move that using a transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use a transform (as @sean suggested).

```html
<svg width="640" height="480" viewbox="0 0 640 480" style="border: 1px dotted black;">
  <g transform="translate(270, 190)">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" stroke="black"></line> 
    <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100" stroke="black"></line> 
    <line x1="100" y1="100" x2="0" y2="100" stroke="black"></line> 
    <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="0" y2="0" stroke="black"></line>
  </g>
</svg>
```